# Find average based upon two conditions; create column from these averages

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I have a df with weather reporting data. It has over 2 million rows and the following columns.

```
ID  MONTH  TEMP   
1   1      0      
1   1      10     

2   1      50     
2   1      60     

3   1      80    
3   1      90     

1   2      0      
1   2      10     

2   2      50     
2   2      60     

3   2      80     
3   2      90
```

I am looking to create an column for the average monthly temperature. I need a faster way than for-loops. The values for average monthly temperature are from the TEMP column. I would like them to be specific to each ID for each MONTH.

```
ID  MONTH  TEMP   AVE MONTHLY TEMP
1   1      0      5
1   1      10     5

2   1      50     55
2   1      60     55

3   1      80     85
3   1      90     85

1   2      0      5
1   2      10     5

2   2      50     55
2   2      60     55

3   2      80     85
3   2      90     85
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['MONTH', 'ID'])['TEMP'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['AVE MONTHLY TEMP']=df.groupby(['ID','MONTH'])['TEMP'].transform('mean')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    ID  MONTH  TEMP  AVE MONTHLY TEMP
0    1      1     0                 5
1    1      1    10                 5
2    2      1    50                55
3    2      1    60                55
4    3      1    80                85
5    3      1    90                85
6    1      2     0                 5
7    1      2    10                 5
8    2      2    50                55
9    2      2    60                55
10   3      2    80                85
11   3      2    90                85
```

Comment: this is a pretty good tutorial for those who find transform a little tricky : https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html

Comment: thanks for contributing to the answer!:) @Datanovice

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution may work better if you have millions of lines of data as those groupings may repeat (ID, MONTH). This makes an assumption that the ID series is always grouped as you have in your data. I'm trying to think out of the box here as you said you have a million lines of data:

```
df['AVG MONTHLY TEMP'] = df.groupby(df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False)['TEMP'].transform('mean')
```

Also, if you average temperatures are *ALWAYS* grouped in two you can do this formula as well:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2)['TEMP'].transform('mean')
```

output:

```
    ID  MONTH  TEMP  AVG MONTHLY TEMP
0    1      1     0                 5
1    1      1    10                 5
2    2      1    50                55
3    2      1    60                55
4    3      1    80                85
5    3      1    90                85
6    1      2     0                 5
7    1      2    10                 5
8    2      2    50                55
9    2      2    60                55
10   3      2    80                85
11   3      2    90                85
```

I hope this help or give ideas as a million lines of data is a lot of data

Comment: This is a great solution too! Ansev's solution worked pretty quickly, but I will use this a some point. Thank you.